# How to use HttpReceiveHttpRequest function in an asynchronous way?

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I tried to use the [`HttpReceiveHttpRequest()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/http/nf-http-httpreceivehttprequest) function with an `LPOVERLAPPED` parameter as below:

```
//some predeclared  parameter 

LPOVERLAPPED myOverLapped;
myOverLapped->Internal = 0;
myOverLapped->InternalHigh = 0;
myOverLapped->DUMMYSTRUCTNAME.Offset = 0;
myOverLapped->DUMMYSTRUCTNAME.OffsetHigh = 0;
myOverLapped->Pointer = 0;

res = HttpReceiveHttpRequest(
    RequestQueueHandle,
    RequestId,
    Flags,
    RequestBuffer,
    RequestBufferLength,
    BytesReturned,
    myOverLapped
);

if(ERROR_IO_PENDING == res)
 while(!GetOverlappedResult(RequestQueueHandle,myOverLapped,RequestBufferLength,FALSE));
 

// other applications
```

However, I could hardly get a correct HTTP request from `RequestBuffer`.
There must be something wrong, could you give me some help?

Comment: See [Synchronous and Asynchronous I/O](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/synchronous-and-asynchronous-i-o). While this covers mostly file I/O the concepts apply to any I/O in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for one thing, the 3rd parameter of `GetOverlappedResult()` expects a *pointer* to a `DWORD`, but you are not giving it a pointer at all.  You likely meant to pass it `BytesReturned` instead of `RequestBufferLength`.

more importantly, you are using an *uninitialized* `OVERLAPPED*` pointer. You need to allocate an `OVERLAPPED` instance for the pointer to point at, and don't free that `OVERLAPPED` until the requested I/O operation is complete.

Try this:

```
LPOVERLAPPED myOverLapped = malloc(sizeof(OVERLAPPED));
memset(myOverLapped, 0, sizeof(OVERLAPPED));
myOverLapped->hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);

res = HttpReceiveHttpRequest(
    RequestQueueHandle,
    RequestId,
    Flags,
    RequestBuffer,
    RequestBufferLength,
    BytesReturned,
    myOverLapped
);

if (ERROR_SUCCESS != res) {
    if (ERROR_IO_PENDING != res) {
      // error handling...
    }
    while (!GetOverlappedResult(RequestQueueHandle, myOverLapped, BytesReturned, FALSE)) {
        if (ERROR_IO_INCOMPLETE != GetLastError()) {
            // error handling...
        }
        // do something else in the meantime...
    }
}

CloseHandle(myOverLapped->hEvent) ;
free(myOverLapped);

// use RequestBuffer up to BytesReturned as needed...
```

Alternatively, since you are waiting on the `OVERLAPPED` in the same code that allocates it, you can just use a local variable instead of dynamic memory, eg:

```
OVERLAPPED myOverLapped;
memset(&myOverLapped, 0, sizeof(myOverLapped));
myOverLapped.hEvent = CreateEvent t(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);

res = HttpReceiveHttpRequest(
    RequestQueueHandle,
    RequestId,
    Flags,
    RequestBuffer,
    RequestBufferLength,
    BytesReturned,
    &myOverLapped
);

if (ERROR_SUCCESS != res) {
    if (ERROR_IO_PENDING != res) {
      // error handling...
    }
    while (!GetOverlappedResult(RequestQueueHandle, &myOverLapped, BytesReturned, FALSE)) {
        if (ERROR_IO_INCOMPLETE != GetLastError()) {
            // error handling...
        }
        // do something else in the meantime...
    }
}

CloseHandle(myOverLapped.hEvent);

// use RequestBuffer up to BytesReturned as needed...
```

Though, on the other hand, calling `GetOverlappedResult()` to wait for a result the way you are doing negates the use of an `OVERLAPPED` at all, so you may as well just get rid of it and use `HttpReceiveHttpRequest()` synchronously instead:

```
res = HttpReceiveHttpRequest(
    RequestQueueHandle,
    RequestId,
    Flags,
    RequestBuffer,
    RequestBufferLength,
    BytesReturned,
    NULL
);

if (ERROR_SUCCESS != res) {
    // error handling...
}

// use RequestBuffer up to BytesReturned as needed...
```

Comment: thx very much.I tried the first given codes.It makes me confused that my POST requests sent by POSTMAN were not alway gotten by GetOverlappedResult(...),but it worked a few times indeed. What I need is an approach to ending the thread running aforementioned httpserver,so synchronous mode may be not suitable.^_^

Answer (score 0):

According to [Synchronization and Overlapped Input and Output](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/synchronization-and-overlapped-input-and-output),

> A thread can manage overlapped operations by either of two methods:
>
> 1. Use the GetOverlappedResult or GetOverlappedResultEx function to wait for the overlapped operation to be completed. If
>    GetOverlappedResultEx is used, the calling thread can specify a
>    timeout for the overlapped operation or perform an alertable wait.
> 2. Specify a handle to the OVERLAPPED structure's manual-reset event object in one of the wait functions and then, after the wait function
>    returns, call GetOverlappedResult or GetOverlappedResultEx. The
>    function returns the results of the completed overlapped operation,
>    and for functions in which such information is appropriate, it reports
>    the actual number of bytes that were transferred

And There is a [Named Pipe Server Using Overlapped I/O](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ipc/named-pipe-server-using-overlapped-i-o) sample **in an asynchronous way**.